# Whenever I grapple onto a RigidBody, the grappling/reeling mechanics glitch out in Unity. How can I fix this?

Tags: unity, c#, game-mechanics, rope-physics, line-renderer

I'm trying to make a game in Unity 2020.1, the feature I'm trying to prototype and test is a grapple gun. The grapple gun should grapple onto walls, and platforms reel the player in. I've implemented this already using the below code:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
       {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(crosshair.transform.position, mousePos - (Vector2) crosshair.transform.position);

            hitPoint = hit.point;

            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                if (!isStrung)
                {
                    if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
                    {
                        Debug.DrawLine(crosshair.transform.position, hitPoint, Color.red, 5);
                        Debug.Log(hitPoint);
                        isStrung = true;
                        distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, hitPoint);

                        springJoint.enabled = true;
                        springJoint.distance = distance;
                        springJoint.connectedAnchor = hitPoint;

                        lineRenderer.enabled = true;
                        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
                        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, hitPoint);
                    }
                }
            }
       }
```

This code handles the raycasting and grappling while this code:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        playerRb.AddForce(Vector2.right * xInput * speed);
        if (isStrung)
        {
            if (springJoint.distance > 2)
            {
                springJoint.distance -= 0.1f;
            }
        }

        if (hitObject)
        {
            hitRb.AddForce(((Vector2)transform.position - hitPoint) * objectPull);
        }


    }
```

handles the reeling.

The problem came in once I added some code to allow the player to grab onto an object with a rigid body, as I wanted to allow the grappling gun to move the object.

An example of the goal I'm working towards in in this game[IQ Ball](https://www.coolmathgames.com/0-iq-ball). I want the line to remain straight, but I also want the reeling effect exhibited in the game above.

Here is the problem-causing code:

```
else if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Object"))
                    {
                        Debug.DrawLine(crosshair.transform.position, hitPoint, Color.green, 5);
                        Debug.Log(hitPoint);
                        distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, hitPoint);

                        springJoint.enabled = true;
                        springJoint.distance = distance;

                        lineRenderer.enabled = true;
                        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
                        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, hitPoint);

                        hitRb = hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

                        springJoint.connectedBody = hitRb;

                        hitObject = true;
                    }

[In FixedUpdate()]
if (hitObject)
        {
            hitRb.AddForce(((Vector2)transform.position - hitPoint) * objectPull);
        }
```

Here's a screen recording which should illustrate the problem:
[Google Drive - Screen Rec](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W8_zoKzQ0zYJ3C2p9DCcu0DeB7XPC4jk/view?usp=sharing)

When I run the game, the grapple gun works fine while I reel onto a wall, with the tag. "walls", but once I grapple onto the RigidBody (the square), the grapple. gun stops working properly. Sometimes, when I grapple onto the RigidBody, there is a green line (same as the one used to show the ray trace), however, I am unsure as to whether this is actually causing the problem.

My full code is in this HasteBin link: [Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/etutuwebag.cs)

Comment: Are you trying something similar. https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/iriw6a/sparks_grapples_portals/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share ?

Comment: Not quite, I'm going for more of a swinging style grapple-gun, where one end is attached to the player and the other is attached to the object/hitpoint. The purpose of the grapple gun is so that the player can move through the level and kill enemies.

Comment: Check the masses